# Select two rows for each value

Tags: mysql, database

My table looks like this:

```
ID - USER  - LOCATION
1  - Steve - home
2  - Steve - work
3  - Steve - school
4  - Eve   - home
5  - Eve   - work
6  - Eve   - school
7  - RJ    - school
etc.
```

How can I get from all users just two positions?

EDIT

The output should be this:

```
ID - USER  - LOCATION
1  - Steve - home
2  - Steve - work
4  - Eve   - home
5  - Eve   - work
7  - RJ    - school
```

Comment: You need to get just 2 rows from table via select?

Comment: I mean for each user two rows.

Comment: Have you tried some select on your own first?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far (including any error messages) and a example of the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,USER  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,LOCATION VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'Steve','home'),
(2  ,'Steve','work'),
(3  ,'Steve','school'),
(4  ,'Eve','home'),
(5  ,'Eve','work'),
(6  ,'Eve','school'),
(7  ,'RJ','school');
```

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user = x.user 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=2;
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | USER  | LOCATION |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Steve | home     |
|  2 | Steve | work     |
|  4 | Eve   | home     |
|  5 | Eve   | work     |
|  7 | RJ    | school   | 
+----+-------+----------+
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I sort it by ID desc? I tryed several ways but it didnt work.

Comment: @EroStefano `AND y.id <= x.id` <-- play with this line

Comment: Im not coming to any solution. 

'SELECT x.* FROM Trackme x JOIN Trackme y ON y.user = x.user AND y.id <= x.id ORDER BY x.id DESC AND y.id DESC GROUP BY x.id HAVING COUNT(*) <=10'

This one doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT a.USER
FROM YourTable a
WHERE LOCATION IN (
                   SELECT DISTINCT(b.LOCATION)
                   FROM YourTable b
                   WHERE USER = a.USER
                   LIMIT 2
                   )
```

Or, if you want 2 specific locations:

```
SELECT USER
FROM YourTable
WHERE LOCATION = 'home' OR LOCATION = 'work'
```

Edit:

It seems that MySql (or some versione) doesn't accept `LIMIT` into a subquery

Comment: The first query returns only the user which have the two first locations ("home" and "work"), for example RJ is not returned.

Comment: Distinct is not a function, and limit without order by is fairly meaningless